# Inserting blog like tags in latex

Tags: symbols, shapes

I want to do tags like the ones used in blogs (like the tags in the picture shown below). Any ideas how I can do them ?

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please, show us your code. Do you want to create a button style?

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you trying to more-or-less duplicate the image shown here?

Comment: @SeanAllred no I am just trying to create tags like this in picture. Baiscally a button like shape which I can write in (the rectangle `things` in the picture) but they wont have an X image on the right

Comment: @Sigur I dont have any code since I am trying to come up with the code. I am trying to create tags like in this image which like you said can be in the shape of buttons

Comment: The most simple way to insert boxes is `\fbox{}`. But it works fine with short texts.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\blogtag}{nobeforeafter,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
  boxsep=0pt,left=3pt,right=3pt,top=4pt,bottom=4pt,tcbox raise base}

\blogtag{mytext}
```

Comment: This is nice, but tags with risers (like `h`) and no hangers (like `j`) don't align vertically with tags with both, or just hangers. Shame...